# Simple Jquery Click not working in WordPress

Tags: jquery

I have included jquery directly from CDN like

`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>` .

I have included my `javascript` file in the footer like

`<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/javascript/tsblog.js"></script>`

my javascript code is

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function($) {
 console.log( "ready!" );
 $("#start-reading").click(function() {
  console.log("click");
 });

});
```

One simple jQuery click function. Here in the console i can see the `ready` message. but on clicking the element with id `start-reading` nothing is happening.

Here is the markup

```
<button id="start-reading">
</button>
```

I'm new to wordpress , is there something wordpress realted which i'm doing wrong ?
Because this is supposed to work in non-wordpress environment.

Comment: You need to use [wp_enqueeue_script()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script).

Answer (score 1):

WP makes sure it only loads scripts once. So it collects all script requests from all plugins and decides the correct order based on dependencies and priority.

To correctly add your script in WordPress you need to use [wp_enqueue_script()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script).

Answer (score 1):

Keep use `jQuery` instead of `$`.  Just like the below code.

```
     jQuery(document).ready(function() {
          console.log( "ready!" );
         jQuery("#start-reading").click(function() {
                console.log("click");
          });

     });
```

Check your element ID whether it's `#start-reading`

Or `#start_reading`.

Comment: you can pass `$` as an argument to the function and use `$` inside, as per the example on the [`wp_enqueue_script` page in codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_Wrappers).

Comment: Of course we can pass it as an argument and work on. But if he uses any other framework that will trouble it some time.  It's just an try.  If it works than it might be a conflict.

Comment: it will not conflict. when you define a var in a function it is locally scoped to that function. it's a different var than the `$` that would be defined outside the function by another framework, and both can coexist.

Answer (score 0):

Use the recommended way, add these code to functions.php

```
function your_theme_scripts() {

    wp_enqueue_script( 'your-theme-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/script.js', array( 'jquery' ), '', true );

}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'your_theme_scripts' );
```

jQuery is already integrated to WordPress, now you can wirte jQuery code to the script.js file.

Comment: I already tried that. In that case even the `ready` message is not printing.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a **dynamically** added **button** (e.g. during the execution  of some code), you can use `onclcick` in the HTML code of the button.

```
jQuery('#parent')
    .html('<button onclick="test_func()">Test</button>');
```

**BUT** the declaration of the target function ( `test_func()` ) must be in the root of the file (not function in function)

Answer (score 0):

Use *wp_enqueue_script* as follows and I figured the last argument which flags for
in footer print as mandatory. Last argument makes difference.

wp_enqueue_script( 'custom_script_unique_handle_name', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/script.js', array( 'jquery' ), '', **true** );